# Ho to get the data on the same level?

Tags: laravel

I use Laravel in the backend and Vue in the frontend. As library, i use DHTMLX Gantt.

To prepare the tasks, i use resource class.

I have a project with many issues. Finally, i need the project data on the same level as the issue data.

What i tried:

ProjectGanttController:

```
    public function index(Request $request, Project $project)
    {
        $tasks['project'] = new ProjectGanttResource($project);
        $tasks['issues'] = ProjectGanttResource::collection($project->issues);

        return response()->json( $tasks);
    }
```

Result:

```
{
    "project": {
        "id": 1,
        "text": "1. Projekt",
        "start_date": "14.10.2020",
        "duration": 10,
        "progress": 0.6
    },
    "issues": [
        {
            "id": 20000000,
            "text": 1. Issue,
            "start_date": "15.10.2020",
            "duration": 10,
            "progress": 0.6
        },
        {
            "id": 20000002,
            "text": 2. Issue,
            "start_date": "15.10.2020",
            "duration": 10,
            "progress": 0.6
        }

    ]
}
```

What i need is:

```
{
    {
        "id": 1,
        "text": "1. Projekt",
        "start_date": "14.10.2020",
        "duration": 10,
        "progress": 0.6
    },
    {
        "id": 20000000,
        "text": 1. Issue,
        "start_date": "15.10.2020",
        "duration": 10,
        "progress": 0.6
    },
    {
        "id": 20000002,
        "text": 2. Issue,
        "start_date": "15.10.2020",
        "duration": 10,
        "progress": 0.6
    }
}
```

I'm struggling with arrays and objects. I tried different approaches, but no success.

How does I prepare the datas to get the right result?

Comment: What you need doesn't look like a valid JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

Both of your models are handled by the same resource.
So you can create a merged collection, and pass it to the resource.

Can you try this :

```
public function index(Request $request, Project $project) {
    return response()->json(
        ProjectGanttResource::collection(
            collect([$project])->merge($project->issues)
        )
    );
}
```

---

If you need different resource for each Model, maybe this would work :
(can try it right now)

```
public function index(Request $request, Project $project) {
    return response()->json(
        collect([$project])
            ->merge($project->issues)
            ->merge($project->todos)
            ->map(function ($object) {
                switch(get_class($object)) {
                    case 'App\Models\Project':
                        return new ProjectGanttResource($object);
                    case 'App\Models\Issue':
                        return new IssueGanttResource($object);
                    case 'App\Models\Todo':
                        return new TodoGanttResource($object);
                }
            })
    );
}
```

Comment: This works! But how can i extend it to todos? An issue has many todos.

Comment: Is `ProjectGanttResource` handling todos ?

Comment: No, i like to create a TodoGanttResource to handle the todos

Comment: I think, i need also a separate resource for issues

Comment: Edit the answer, but I can try it now.

Comment: With your help, i found the final solutions

Comment: Fine, Can you edit your post and past it ? Can be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public function index(Request $request, Project $project)
    {
        $projects = new ProjectGanttResource($project);
        $issues = IssueGanttResource::collection($project->issues);
        $allTodos = $project->issues->map(function ($issue, $key) {
            if(!empty($issue->todos)) {
                return $issue->todos;
            }
        });

        $todos = TodoGanttResource::collection($allTodos[0]);
        $tasks = collect([$projects])->merge($issues)->merge($todos);
        return response()->json($tasks);
    }
```